# Corpus for text classification with annotated support phrases

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, text-classification

I am looking for corpora for text classification with annotated support phrases.

Support phrases = phrases that explain why a text was given a label.

For example, if the text is "*The patient works at Firm X. He uses the computer all day long, and goes to the gym twice a week. He has 2 dogs.*" and the label is "Patient is a computer user", then the support phrase is "He uses the computer all day long".

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.